# initialising a pointer without giving an address

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I want to know the statement below is not valid,

```
int* p;
*p = 3;
```

but this statement below is

```
int* p; int a;
a = 9;
p = &a;
*p = 3;
```

Why cannot I give *p a value before giving it an address but can give it after assigning an address. Thanks

Comment: You can't use a variable's value until you assign the variable a value. What's so confusing about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being initialized to point to an address, a pointer will contain some trash address, which is what you attempt to write to in the first example. To be valid, it is essential that the pointer references some valid memory that you own, which requires that you set it to an address.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is just a special type of variable that holds a memory address as its value. Before being initialized, it could possibly point to any random memory address.

Dereferencing a pointer (using the `*p = 3` syntax) is telling the computer to go to the *memory address pointed to* by `p`, and store the value 3 in that location.

So it should be obvious that without a valid memory location, this is problematic. Here's one possible way of obtaining a valid memory address via allocation:

```
int *p = new int;
*p = 3;
```

The first line does two things: 1) allocates memory on the heap for an int, and 2) sets the value of pointer `p` to the address of the allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, specially the new int.

Comment: Don't actually use `new`, though, use `std::unique_ptr`.